# Shed foundation beams robustness

Tags: wood, foundation, shed

I’m building a 18.2 feet (555cm) by 15 feet (460) shed, and I’m not sure the foundation beams I’m using are strong enough.

The blue frame is made of 45x145mm, which is slightly higher than 2x6 (I’m in Europe). The joists are spaced 50cm (1.64 feet) apart.

The supporting red beams are sistered 45x145mm, but because I can’t find a supplier that has them in the right length (18.2 feet or 555cm), I’m splitting each beam in half, using 2 times sistered 45x145mm that are 277cm long (9.1 feet). So that’s 4 pieces of wood per red beam, is this bad for overall robustness?

The read beams have an overhang of 51cm (20 inches) on both sides and are supported every 200cm (78.7 inches) by concrete poles. Is this enough?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Usually with beams, one side you want short, long, short(4.5, 9, 4.5) and the other side two (9) pieces, with supports under the breaks.  Sizes are examples only, size to your need.

Comment: What's your locality? My problem is that I'm in the US, so I'm familiar with US lumber species and grades and can map those to design strengths. Even with the same species, a good grade versus bad grade can more than double a beam's strength. As long as your locality's grading and design standards are available and in English, though, I may be able to help.

Comment: Your concrete supports may or may not have sufficient resistance to pushover loads from wind and the like. If the soil conditions are decent and the soil comes up very near the connection to the beams, then chances are good. In the US a soil classification report is commonly required for something like this, although local building officials will often give you a soil classification for checking foundation strength

Comment: I assume that you forgot to draw the center post. That one gets more load than any of the others.

Comment: The UK uses "C16" and "C24" for classifying structural lumber. You'll need a spec like that from the supplier for your 45mmx145mm lumber if I'm to have any chance of helping.

Comment: I’ll let the resident engineers weigh in, but I’m pretty sure two sections of 90mm x 145mm butted over a post would be better beams/girders than sistered 45x145. Less work, as well. (As an aside, I’d design the roof with a ridge beam for easier building. Just my opinion, though.)

Comment: @crip659 thanks for that, so would something like a 2x6 be enough for the red beams in your opinion?

Comment: @popham Yes I want to go with C16, but again I'm having a hard time finding those long red beams in the length I need them to be. Is it ok to split them in half in your opinion?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Thanks for the roof tip. I do live in a region where we get at least one huge storm a year and the weather can be pretty rough. Would a ridge beam help solidify the structure as well?

Comment: 2x6s are good for at least 6ft open span.  With supports under the splices, more supports needed, they should be plenty.

Comment: @crip659 So 2x6s with a 6ft span, concrete polls as shown in attached pictures, looks good to you?

Comment: Regarding the ridge beam, I’d again defer to actual engineers. My intuition is that it will help a little, as you’ll have a support underneath it that carries load to the foundation.

Answer (score 2):

A continuous beam across all three supports would sag less than your drawing's detail with a cut over the center support. The maximum stress in the beam wouldn't change, however. If the continuous beam has sufficient strength, then so too does your drawing's configuration. Compare M<sub>1</sub> from Figure 29 of [this document](https://awc.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/AWC-DA6-BeamFormulas-0710.pdf) to M<sub>max</sub> from Figure 1 of the [same document](https://awc.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/AWC-DA6-BeamFormulas-0710.pdf) if you want to check for yourself. You seem confident that the continuous beam would have been sufficiently strong. I'm not at all confident in that belief even if you're using C24 lumber.

C16 lumber isn't quite up to US standards for building those beams. In the US, at least #2 grade softwoods are used for your application, and C16 lumber is about halfway between #2 and #3 grade. This is handy in that if a US design table says that your beam wouldn't be strong enough under our #2 softwoods, then it wouldn't be strong enough under C16 lumber. C24 lumber is basically #1 grade in the US, so if a US design table says that your beam would be strong enough under #2 softwoods (or #1 softwoods if you can find such a table), then it would also be strong enough under C24 lumber. [IRC R602.7](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch06_SecR602.7) has tables that you can use in this manner. I'm skeptical that any European building authority will accept my cross-my-heart-and-hope-to-die authority, though.

There's actually a little more complexity than I just indicated. Eurocode recommends a range for residential floor loads between 1.5 kPa and 2.0 kPa (it's up to a "National Annex" to choose actual values, where the Eurocode range is technically just a recommendation). In the US we use approximately 1.5 kPa for bedrooms and 2.0 kPa everywhere else (30 psf and 40 psf by our code). I don't know how Eurocode's roof load requirements compare to the US's. I do know that both codes like to specify loads based on a 50 year return interval, but "30 psf snow load" from your local authority could mean something totally different than "30 psf snow load" from my local authority in the US. (The US just recently abandoned the 50 year return interval for snow loading for *very* interesting reasons.)

Simplifying the geometry for convenience and pushing typical numbers through the US design code with zero snow load on the roof (that just leaves the roof weight plus a 20 psf live load that's associated with the construction process), I anticipate that your outer beams are overloaded with a demand/capacity ratio of 110% and that your middle beam is overloaded with a demand/capacity ratio of 116%. Taking the roof live load down to 15 psf from 20 psf (out of spec with the US code) and the interior storage load down to 34 psf from 40 psf (also out of spec with the US code), my anticipated demand/capacity ratios come down to 100% (I would want them down around at most 85% given my simplifying assumptions). Another 50 mm in beam depth or C24 lumber would certainly bring things within spec (I anticipate).

Strength is an ultimate limit state, but beams also get designed for serviceability limit states. In particular, the beam must not sag beyond some prescribed limit. If I was building your structure in the US, the sag limit would be 1/360 times the beam length. Eurocode recommends a multiplier value within the range 1/300 to 1/500. To know for sure your particular value, you would have to rummage around in your National Annex. For your beam's span-to-depth ratio, (2000mm)/(145mm) = 14, I'm confident that the sagging would satisfy my 1/360 multiplier's constraint.

*Analysis*:

Without specific information about your locality, I contextualized the design within the US framework. The 16 from "C16" indicates a maximum design bending stress of 16 MPa. There's a document called EN-384 that clarifies that this is the 5th percentile maximum bending stress for that lumber. In the US we use a 5th percentile criterion also. This makes the conversion to a US equivalent lumber very easy.

Under Eurocode, the authors recommend that your National Annex adjust the 16 MPa for moisture content and load duration. Eurocode's "Service Class 2" and "Load Duration Class" of "Long Term Action" correspond to common tabulated values in the US and your likely scenario, so I map the 16 MPa to (0.70)(16MPa). For solid wood, it's tempting to apply an additional adjustment factor of (1/1.3) from Eurocode. I see this 1.3 as a safety factor applied to the 5th percentile strength, so I'll ignore it for a while. There's a competing safety factor under the US code. The 5th percentile strength of C16 lumber under "Service Class 2" and "Long Term Action," then, is (16MPa)(0.70) = 11 MPa.

The US code, [the NDS](https://awc.org/publications/2018-nds/), also exposes a 5th percentile strength. There's a lovely table in the NDS, Table 4.3.1, that converts tabulated maximum bending stress values (from the [NDS Supplement](https://awc.org/publications/2018-nds-supplement/)) to beam specific maximum values:

[image: NDS Table]

I already have F<sub>b</sub>' from Eurocode. It's that 11 MPa value from (0.7)(16MPa). I want to compute the F<sub>b</sub> value. Then I can look at the NDS Supplement to compare your lumber's F<sub>b</sub> to that of other species and grades. I'll ignore another safety factor on the 5th percentile strength, the ϕ term in the equation, because I also ignored the (1/1.3) safety factor term in the Eurocode strength computation:

F<sub>b</sub> = 11MPa / (C<sub>M</sub> C<sub>t</sub> C<sub>L</sub> C<sub>F</sub> C<sub>fu</sub> C<sub>i</sub> C<sub>r</sub> (2.54) λ).

The different terms in this equation follow from conditions on the wood used to find the Eurocode maximum bending stress.

- C<sub>M</sub> = 1.0 because the moisture content is below 19% and the "Service Class 2" that I mentioned earlier is for moisture content below 20%;
- C<sub>t</sub> = 1.0 because the temperature is reasonable ("Service Class 2" is calibrated for a temperature of 20.°C);
- C<sub>L</sub> = 1.0 because I'm comparing wood strengths, not different stability treatments from the two codes;
- C<sub>F</sub> = 1.3 for a 2x6 under Chapter 4 from the NDS Supplement, where this basically matches the C16 spec's 16 MPa for a 150mm depth (a size effect will lower the 16 MPa to smaller values as the depth increases);
- C<sub>fu</sub> = 1.0 because the lumber is standing on its edge;
- C<sub>i</sub> = 1.0 because the 16 MPa from the C16 specification is for lumber that hasn't been incised (you use a value less than 1.0 if there are those tiny little cuts that they make in pressure treated wood to help the chemicals penetrate);
- C<sub>r</sub> = 1.0 because the 16 MPa from the C16 specification is for a single board, not 3 or more boards acting together;
- λ = 0.7 because the "Long Term Action" specification in Eurocode is based on a 10 year time frame just like the NDS's storage (see Appendix N from the NDS). It's no coincidence that Eurocode and the NDS both apply the same 0.7 factor.

Evaluating that mess, I get F<sub>b</sub> = 700 psi. If you're actually looking at the NDS Supplement, you can't just look at the Southern Pine values because the tabulated values already included the C<sub>F</sub> value (you would look up (1.3)(700psi) = 910 psi). The 700 psi pretty much evenly splits halfway between the #2 and #3 grade values for US softwoods. Using C24's 24 MPa instead of the 16 MPa, I get F<sub>b</sub> = 1050 psi. This is a little better than at least one of the #1 grade US softwoods.

*What about that 1.3 safety factor?:*

Eurocode uses a 1.3 safety factor on the 5th percentile maximum bending stress and the US code uses a safety factor of 1/ϕ = 1/0.85 = 1.2. That sounds like a problem, but it's not. Both the US's and Eurocode's design framework apply multipliers to loads to account for variability in the loads. These multipliers appear to bring the two frameworks into close alignment.

Defining the 5th percentile maximum bending stress by F<sub>unsafe</sub> = (0.7)(16MPa), Eurocode uses F<sub>unsafe</sub>/1.3, and the US code uses F<sub>unsafe</sub>/1.2. Under the US code, the governing load case for your center beam (without load from the roof) is almost certainly

1.2(dead load stress) + 1.6(live load stress) ≤ F<sub>unsafe</sub>/1.2.

Under Eurocode, there exists a load case for your center beam that looks like

1.1(dead load stress) + 1.5(live load stress) ≤ F<sub>unsafe</sub>/1.3.

Moving the denominators from the right hand sides to the other side, these inequalities become

1.41(dead load stress) + 1.88(live load stress) ≤ F<sub>unsafe</sub>

versus

1.43(dead load stress) + 1.95(live load stress) ≤ F<sub>unsafe</sub>.

They're very nearly the exact same inequality.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write such a comprehensive answer to my question, that’s much appreciated! In all honesty, your expertise seems to be beyond my range of understanding. The main takeaway I got from your analysis is that especially since this shed will be used as a workshop with a lot of heavy tools in it, I probably should increase the depth of the sistered red beams to 245mm (9.6 inches). Unless I can find a supplier that has the right length, I’ll have to split them in the middle and I take good note of your comment on that.

Comment: Another thing I was worried about is the spacing of the joists, but based on your analysis and on the fact that I will increase depth by nearly 70%, I think both the spacing and span should now be ok.

Comment: One last thing was the roof, and especially because I live in an area where we get snow (not a ton, but still) and a LOT of wind (at least one hurricane-force storm a year), I really want that to be robust. Here some weather data from the place I live in [(precipitation, wind)](https://imgur.com/a/DYoKyLb). Again I’m no engineer but I have a feeling the trusses I’m using for the roof are just not going to cut it for a storm, what do you think? I’ve seen those hurricane brackets online, but do they really help?

Comment: @Moyk, in the US we have engineering codes, but then we also have the International Residential Code. That document has tabulated joist sizes, rafter sizing, etc. based on the engineering codes You may have some sort of local code that's similar. Another option for the beams is just a concrete slab.

Comment: What are the joist lengths? 230 cm? Relative to 90x245 beams, single 45x200 joists sound about proportionate. Your center beam has to carry 460cm / 2 = 230 cm width of floor area, whereas each joist is carrying a width of 50 cm. That's about 20% of the load. Each 45mm thickness carries half, so 45x245 joists would have about 40% of the beam's stress. Halving the depth will result in a strength larger than 25%. My first guess is in the neighborhood of 30% to 35%. That's where my 45x200 came from.

Comment: Unfortunately that weather data is pretty useless. The design loads are typically predicated on the average worst storm that shows up every 50 years. Averages are no good because you need to know about the edges of the distribution, not the mean value.

Comment: The hurricane brackets are to prevent your roof from flying away. The gabled roof shape is kinda wing shaped, so as the wind flows over, it generates a suction pressure on the roof. In the US, you can figure out wind pressures based on [IRC R301.2.1](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-3-building-planning#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch03_SecR301.2.1). You install enough of the brackets so that their strength adds up to the uplift.

Comment: Loaded rafters have effectively a hinge where they meet. Under gravity load or wind uplift, the rafters can cause substantial spreading or narrowing of the walls as the hinge opens or closes. As drawn, your plates along the ridge fight against this hinge motion. Typical alternatives are a ridge beam or rafter ties.

Comment: The blue joists are 45x145mm and 450cm in length, not 210cm. They're spaced 50cm apart. 

The red beams are 45x245mm and 550cm in total length, split in 2 timbers of 275cm. But since they’re sistered, that’s 4 timbers per red beam. They're spaced 190cm apart and there's 3 of them.

Does that make sense?

Comment: @Moyk, by 230 cm, I mean their span length. A 90x245 and a pair of sistered 45x245s are effectively the same thing in a beam. The "tributary width" of the center beam is 190 cm, and the "tributary widths" of the outer beams are only 95 cm. The outer beams get loads from the roof, though, so as the roof load increases their demand ramps up beyond the center beam's demand.

Comment: I see, but terms of beam "thickness", those numbers seem to add up and the shed should hold?

Comment: @Moyk, I'm uncomfortable without heavily qualifying the answer. It really depends on the design loads. In the US, we've got a quirky area in Missouri with very high earthquake demand, for instance. You would never guess. There aren't little quakes all the time, but the 50 year return interval quake is no joke. Similarly, your typical little bit of snow may not reflect the 50 year snow event at all. 45x245 joists are definitely okay (maybe even wastefully so), where I can confidently say that because they don't get loaded by snow or wind. Similarly, the center beam is definitely okay.